# Photologue zip uploader not working

Tags: python, django, photologue

According to the docs, The 'zip upload' functionality has been moved to a custom admin page as of 11/4/2014. This functionality is nowhere to be found, and my galleries upload field in admin disallows uploading zip files.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in Photologue 3.1 - the templates required for this feature were missing.

Photologue 3.1.1 fixes this :-)